# Confusion with Pointers Increment

Tags: c, pointers

```
char *str = "string" ;
char *end = str;
while(*(end+1) != '\0') {
    end++;
}

while(str < end) {
    char temp = *str;
    *str = *end;
    *end = temp;
    str++;
    end--;
}`
```

EDIT: 
Are both these`*str = *end`,  `*str++ = *end` invalid?

The above code gives error at that line.

Aren't `str` and `end` pointing to a read only part in memory whether it be post increment?

Comment: They're both invalid. Why do you think they aren't?

Comment: The first line should be `char str[] = "string";`. That way the string is in writable memory, and you can change it. Technically, your code has undefined behavior, which means that it may or may not work, depending on whether it does or not.

Comment: MY BAD. I meant  *str++ = *end;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *str = "string" ;
```

Is a [string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go) placed in a read-only data section.

In this line:

```
*str = *end;
```

is trying to modify the string, you would probably get a segfault..

Same for `*str++ = *end`, both are invalid.

To make this code work, change

```
char *str = "string";
```

to

```
char str[] = "string";
```

But note that you can not use `*str++` because array names are constant (not modifiable lvalue)

Comment: My bad. I meant  *str++ = *end;

Comment: `*str++ = *end;` is also modifying the string before incrementing the pointer.

Comment: Right, so it is invalid. How can I make this code work while using char pointers?

Comment: Change `char *str = "string" ;` to `char str[] = "string";`

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.